# Разыскной или розыскной?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: "оперативно-р**а**зыскные мероприятия" или "оперативно-р**о**зыскные"? Встречала в документах оба варианта, но всё-таки как правильно?

Answer (score 3):

В двух словах.
До недавнего времени правильным считалось розыскной. Это рассматривалось как единственное исключение из общего правила правописания приставки раз/рас-роз/рос. Такое исключение историческими лингвистическими причинами объяснить невозможно. Их следует искать среди тайн 30-х годов прошлого века, когда это написание было впервые закреплено нормативно (в документах).

Сейчас предлагается вернуться к естественному написанию "разыскной" - и это одна из немногих новаций, связанных с попыткой корректировки свода правил правописания (группа ИРЯ РАН под руководством В. В. Лопатина), нашедших относительное понимание большинства и носителей, и специалистов.

Так что на современном этапе написание **раз**ыскной следует считать верным.
Подробно - [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_2_razysknoj/)

Answer (score 0):

В безударном положении употребляется только приставка РАЗ-(РАС-). Т.е. оперативно-рАзыскные мероприятия.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет общего правила согласен, но для меня лично дико выглядит словосочетание "оперативно-разыскные мероприятия". И я бы написал "оперативно-рОзыскные мероприятия". Более того - поисковая система Гугль со мной согласна. Результаты таковы:

через букву А - примерно 658 000

через букву О - примерно 1 600 000

Как говорится, миллион мух не может ошибаться.

А одна из ссылок ведет даже на [Википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), на которой пишут следующее:

*Несмотря на распространенность написания "оперативно-розыскная деятельность" (в таком виде термин употребляется в законодательстве[2], научной и учебной литературе[3]), по правилам современного русского языка правильным является только написание оперативно-разыскная деятельность. Слово "розыскной" и иных производные от него сочетания в современных словарях русского языка и сводах правил русской орфографии не встречаются[4][5].
По всей видимости, вариант "оперативно-розыскная" является сленговым, укоренившимся в специальной литературе.*

Comment: Вы с таким  уважением пишете о Википедии... Но внимательно ли Вы прочитали то, что скопировали? Да и заголовочное слово в статье - оперативно-рАзыскная деятельность. Нам может что-то не нравится в правописании, но первый признак литературного языка - нормированность, кодифицированность (т.е. закрепление нормы в словарях). И мы обязаны подчиняться. У себя в записной книжке можно писать как хочется. В официальных, публичных текстах соблюдение норм обязательно.

Comment: Прокомментируйте тогда последнее предложение цитаты из википедии: " По всей видимости, вариант "оперативно-розыскная" является сленговым, укоренившимся в специальной литературе". На мой взгляд, нормы языка не являются чем-то статичным и они со временем меняются. Более того - исключения из исключений вполне могут быть. Но очень странно, что в случае именно данного слова оно раньше никак не было отмечено, а в словарях давались оба варианта: и "розыскной", и "разыскной".
P.S. я лично за унификацию, но как минимум инерцию победить в этом случае будет сложно

Comment: >>>" По всей видимости, вариант "оперативно-розыскная" является сленговым, укоренившимся в специальной литературе".  
    
А что тут комментировать? Вполне ясно сказано. Не совсем точно сформулировано, по вполне понятно.

Остальное у вас - пустопорожние слова ни о чем. В каких словарях давались оба варианта, когда это было, в чем разница?!  И самое главное - что из этого следует?

Comment: Ссылка, данная в ответе, приведет Вас на "Грамоту" - там все очень подробно. И еще мы обсуждали это в соседнем вопросе.

Comment: Соглашусь, будем писать "разыскной". Единственное, что хотелось бы все-таки подборочку по современным словарям увидеть. В частности, Соловьева, ну, ладно.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что правильно Оперативно-рОзыскная, т.к. от слова Уголовный рОзыск, который этой деятельностью и занимается.

Comment: Этого недостаточно, как видно из прежних ответов и комментариев к ним: здесь проблема с необычной приставкой.