# Объясните комбинацию НИ и НЕ в тексте «Интернационала»

Tags: не-или-ни

> Никто не даст нам избавленья:
>   **Ни** бог, **ни** царь и **не** герой.

[Интернационал](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD))

Comment: Вопрос взят из ответа Ольги на вопрос Разыскной или розыскной? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4200/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9

Answer (score 6):

Григорий Прутцков
["Ни бог, ни царь и не герой"](https://pruttskov.livejournal.com/570855.html)

> Ещё в шестом классе меня заинтересовало, почему в тексте гимна КПСС "Интернационал" в строке "Никто не даст нам избавленья - ни бог, ни царь и не герой" два раза НИ, а третий - НЕ. Ни один учитель русского языка в моей школе не мог мне этого объяснить. Знакомая преподавательница, к которой я ездил в девятом классе готовиться к сочинению, предположила, что "и не" тождественно "ни". Но предположила очень неуверенно, и сомнения у меня остались.
>
> На журфаковских курсах для старшеклассников и абитуриентов лекции по русскому языку читал Дитмар Эльяшевич Розенталь. Однажды я набрался смелости и подошёл к нему после лекции с этим вопросом. Розенталь выслушал, внимательно посмотрел на меня и сказал:
>
> – Этого не может быть. Должно быть три "ни".
>
> – Но в энциклопедии написано "ни бог, ни царь и НЕ герой", - не унимался я.
>
> – Молодой человек, вы, наверное, что-то перепутали, - деликатно предположил Розенталь.
>
> На следующую лекцию я принёс из дома толстенный том энциклопедии. Едва занятие окончилось, я показал Розенталю страницу со статьёй "Интернационал".
> – Пойдёмте ко мне на кафедру, посмотрим, - кивнул Дитмар Эльяшевич.
> Мы зашли. Розенталь сел за стол, надел очки и придвинул к себе энциклопедию. Некоторое время он сидел молча, затем оторвал взгляд от книги и внимательно посмотрел на меня.
>
> –Ошибка, - изрёк он.
>
> –Как такое может быть?! - похолодел я от изумления.
>
> –Да, тиражируемая ошибка, - повторил Розенталь. - Кто-то один ошибся, опубликовал, и все не задумываясь перепечатывали гимн с этого варианта.
>
> Я не мог выговорить слова.
>
> – Вы молодец, что заметили, - похвалил меня Дитмар Эльяшевич. - Приходите к нам учиться.

Comment: А кто автор-то? (этого текста, а не ошибки)

Comment: Григорий Прутцков, это видно если перейти по ссылке

Comment: А как Вы объясните "сочетание союзов" И НИ? Ведь если бы не было союза И, то и не было бы "ошибки": Никто не даст нам избавленья: ни бог, ни царь, ни герой. Ошибка здесь не случайная (кто-то один ошибся), как сочетаются повторяющийся союз НИ...НИ и соединительный союз И? Конструкция не совсем стандартная.

Comment: @Jasmin,  Вы хотите угадать ход мысли того, кто сделал эту ошибку?

Comment: @Jasmin, По-моему, так. Есть отрицание (не даст)  с итрицательным местоимением *никто*, далее *никто* выступает как обобщающее слово, за ним перечисление с частицей НИ. А союз И допустим, как при любом перечислении.

Comment: Я думаю, что это не ошибка, а преднамеренное решение, иначе бы ее давно обнаружили и уж точно не стали бы тиражировать. Что означает встреча двух соединительных союзов И + НИ?

Answer (score 4):

Воспоминания Прутцкова, приведённые в ответе М_Г, интересны. Но, к сожалению, в то время, когда Прутцков учился на журфаковских курсах, Дитмару Эльяшевичу было уже под девяносто…

Только этим и могу объяснить то, что Розенталь не вспомнил изданную им в 1962 году книгу *"Вопросы русского правописания"*, в которой на странице 94 он сам рекомендовал написание ***"и не герой"***:

> Употребление повторяющегося союза-частицы ***ни*** в значении "и не"
>   делает лишним наличие при одном из однородных членов предложения союза
>   ***и*** (вместо ***ни*** можно употребить ***и не***); ср.: *Никто не даст нам избавленья: **ни** бог, **ни** царь **и не герой.***

И в БСЭ, изданной в 1937 году, написание ***"и не герой"*** не было ошибкой. Такого написания требовали правила.

Из справочника для работников печати А.Б. Шапиро и М.И. Уарова *"Орфография, пунктуация и техника корректуры"* (М., 1933):

> В оборотах типа ***"ни бог, ни царь и не герой"*** после союза ***и***
>   следует писать ***не***, а не ***ни***, так как "и не" по значению
>   тождественны с ***ни***.

**P.S.**

А может, Прутцков что-то не так вспомнил?..

**Розенталь. 1962 г.:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Встретилось мне и другое понимание того, как следует писать эту строку из "Интернационала".

Из книги В.Ф. Ивановой *"Трудные вопросы орфографии"* (М., 1982):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Итак, посовещались и решили: **В оборотах типа "ни бог, ни царь и не герой" после союза и следует писать не, а не ни, так как "и не" по значению тождественны с ни.** (Из справочника для работников печати А.Б. Шапиро и М.И. Уварова "Орфография, пунктуация и техника корректуры" (М., 1933)

**Но почему тождественно,** откуда такое откровение? Как-нибудь объяснить это не озаботились, время тогда такое было.

А в современной орфографии, похоже, **это постановление устарело, прав был Розенталь,** когда разговаривал с Прутцковым, хотя ему и было тогда под девяносто. Вероятно, **он высказал свое личное мнение**, а в 1962 году писал так, как "постановили".

**Сочетание И НИ используется часто и во многих конструкциях, замены НИ на  НЕ не требуется.**

**Это можно объяснить так**: Когда появляется союз И, то НИ выполняет не функцию союза, а функцию усилительной частицы.

**Примеры:**

До этого нам, конечно, **ни Бог, ни царь и ни герой** ― никто не нужен. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 3 (1978)]

Как бы они там **ни орали, и ни стучали, и ни сучили** кулаками. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 3 (1978)]

Казалось, **ни тридцать лет назад и ни сто тридцать лет** назад, когда Пушкин привёл на эту площадь своего героя, не был дивный Петр так велик, как сегодня. [Василий Гроссман. Все течет (1955-1963) // «Октябрь», 1989]

Они выбежали на крыльцо - молодой месяц, как попугай, сидел на ветке. **И ни следа, ни пятнышка!**  [Сергей Козлов. Новогодняя сказка // «Мурзилка», 2003]

Похоже, они забрались в такую глушь, что везде только **кусты да болота и ни одной деревни**. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]

Музыка выворачивала мне душу, но слёзы не приходили, **и ни до него мне было, и ни до кого, и ни до чего…** [Ирина Муравьева. Мещанин во дворянстве (1994)]

Answer (score 1):

1) **Никто не даст нам избавленья** ―

**Ни бог, ни царь и ни герой**.

Интернационал ― Вставай, проклятьем заклеймённый (**ориг. версия 1939 г**.):

https://lyricsworld.ru/Internacional/Vstavayproklyatem-zakleymennyiy-origversiya-1939g-632003.html

2) **Пояснение:**

***не даст*** ― отрицание, частица НЕ;

***никто*** ― отрицательная приставка НИ со значением усиления отрицания;

***ни бог, ни царь***  ― соединительный повторяющийся союз НИ...НИ, частица НИ со значением усиления отрицания;

***и ни герой*** ― замыкающий соединительный союз И и частица НИ со значением усиления отрицания.

3) Вариант  ***ни бог, ни царь и не герой*** не очень логичен: однородный ряд раскрывает содержание обобщающего слова ***никто***, все его члены однородны по смыслу и должны иметь одинаковую усилительную частицу НИ.

***Ни бог, не царь*** разделены запятой (смысловое единство не обозначено).

4) Варианты  текста связаны с союзом И.

Answer (score 1):

В тексте - правильно. Объяснять тут особо ничего не нужно, смысл предложения диктует и выбор частицы.

Но в силу некоторых причин возникло желание прокомментировать историю с упоминанием Розенталя. Если принять за правду рассказанную неким Прутцковым и здесь приведенную версию, то Розенталь ошибался. Возможно, уже в силу возраста. **"И ни"** - не бывает. Это как минимум либо оксюморон, либо нежелательная тавтология (хотя, может, и то и другое).

Давайте от печки. НИ - в отличие он НЕ - частица **усилительная**. Отрицательной она становится только условно - при наличии собственно отрицания, явного или подразумеваемого. Но ведь и частица/союз И (в нашем случае это скорее союз, но такому пониманию несколько мешает наличие запятой между первыми однородными членами, впрочем это не принципиально для контекста рассуждений) выполняет такую же усилительную роль, в случае частицы - явно, в случае союза через связку с использованным ранее отрицанием ("не даст").

Таким образом сочетания "и ни" в принципе невозможно, за исключением случаев, когда они поставлены по другим мотивам, т.е. когда либо "И", либо "НИ" входит в состав нечленимой единицы: составного союза или устоявшегося сочетания соответственно.

Вместо дальнейших пояснений приведу исчерпывающую цитату.

> Примечание 3.
>
> ...
>
> ***Повторяющаяся частица "ни" употребляется в функции соединительного союза
>   и по значению равна сочетанию "и не"***; ср.: На душе ни весело, ни
>   грустно. — На душе и не весело, и не грустно; Обалдуй не умел ни петь,
>   ни плясать, отроду не сказал не только умного, даже нужного слова
>   (Т.). Это значение у частицы "ни" особенно заметно проявляется в
>   конструкциях с повторяющейся отрицательной частицей не, когда
>   последнее отрицание усиливается частицей даже: Там, откуда ушел
>   человек, принимаются почему-то не мальвы, не ромашки, не колокольчики,
>   не купальницы, ни даже васильки, а вот именно бурьян да крапива
>   (Сол.). ***Употребление частицы ни исключает союз и; ср.: ни даже
>   васильки — и даже не васильки.***
>
> ...
>
> Примечание. Лишь в некоторых случаях при однородных членах предложения
>   встречается союз и перед ни: Мне не подходит ни то и ни другое; также
>   в разговорной речи: Конечно, с этим можно согласиться, хоть и ни вам,
>   ни нам пользы не будет (здесь и входит в состав союза хоть и).

http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.58

И в качестве развития темы - о том, что заставило меня освежить этот вопрос.
Обсуждалась фраза из перевода чешской (как утверждается - народной) сказки "Хитроумная дочь".

Там Король говорит Пастуху:

> – Так вот, передай своей дочери: если она явится ко мне (не)(ни)
>   пешком, (не)(ни) верхом, (не)(ни) голая и (не)(ни) одетая, (не)(ни)
>   днем и (не)(ни) ночью, (не)(ни) о полудни, (не)(ни) утром, то я женюсь
>   на ней...

К сожалению, мне не удалось поучаствовать в той дискуссии напрямую, а склонились к неверному (по моему мнению) решению - писать через НИ, причем во всех случаях. На мой взгляд здесь лучше бы все через "не" писать. Если в тексте "Интернационала" первые два "ни" - но никак не последнее! - оправданы наличием явного отрицания ("никто не даст"), то в сказке это нет, городить перемежающиеся "не" и "ни" просто нет резона. Да и по смыслу - никак не подходит.